# Need help on WebDriverWait text_to_be_present_in_element_value

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait

I'm trying to wait until the web element changes its status to 'finished'?  Can someone please review my code where I am not doing it correct?

I see the application status has changed to 'finished', but the code execution does not proceed? I am getting TimeOutException.

```
 def check_status(self,myString):
        table = self.browser.find_element_by_id(self.table_id)
        col= table.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//tr[contains(.,'" + myString + "')]//td[5]")
        print(col.text)
        if col.text=='finished':
            return col.text
        else:
            try:
                wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 180)
                element = wait.until(
                    EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.XPATH, "//tr[contains(.,'" + myString + "')]//td[5]"), 'finished'))
                print(element)
                return col.text
            except:
                col.text
            raise TimeoutException("Not Finished yet")
```

I expect that once the status is changed to finished it should proceed further execution.

Comment: Try EC.text_to_be_present_in_element

Answer (score 0):

I had to change something but it's work fine for me, element to be clickable works better in my opinion and it won't do anything until element will appear:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//tr[contains(text(),'your string')]//tr[5]")))
print("Finished")
```